# How can I apply image write file path?

Tags: python, opencv

```
i = 2 #int
cv2.imwrite([r'C:\Users\Desktop\result (' + str(i) + ').png'], result) #result is 16bit image
```

I want to save image under the name 'result (2).png'

Because, `i` is stuck in 'for loop'.

However, the code above causes an error.

Please help me.

add)

```
## Flat Field Correction (FFC) ##

import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numba as nb
import multiprocessing as multi
import parmap
import time
start = time.time()

B = cv2.imread(r'D:\remedi\Exercise\Xray\Offset.png', -1) # offset image

for i in range(2,3):

    org_I = cv2.imread(r'D:\remedi\Exercise\Xray\objects\object (' + str(i) + ').png', -1) # original image

    w = cv2.imread(r'D:\remedi\Exercise\Xray\white\white (' + str(i) + ').png', -1) # white image

    ## dead & bad pixel correction
    corrected_w = w.copy()
    corrected_org_I = org_I.copy()

    c = np.mean(corrected_w)
    p = np.abs(corrected_w - c)

    sens = 0.7
    [num_y, num_x] = np.where((p < c*sens) | (p > c*sens))
    #[num_y, num_x] = np.where((corrected_w < c*0.97) | (corrected_w > c*1.03))

    ar = np.zeros((3,3))
    ar2 = np.zeros((3,3))

    #pool = multi.Pool(processes=6)
    iter = num_y.shape[0]
    for n in range(iter):   
        #parmap.map(bad_pixel_correction, [n, num_y, num_x, ar, ar2, corrected_w, corrected_org_I], pm_pbar=True, pm_processes=6)
        for j in range(-1,2):
            for k in range(-1,2):
                if num_y[n]+j == -1 or num_x[n]+k == -1 or num_y[n]+j == 576 or num_x[n]+k == 576:
                    ar[j+1][k+1] = 0
                    ar2[j+1][k+1] = 0
                else:
                    ar[j+1][k+1] = corrected_w[num_y[n]+j][num_x[n]+k]
                    ar2[j+1][k+1] = corrected_org_I[num_y[n]+j][num_x[n]+k]
        ar[1][1] = 0
        ar2[1][1] = 0
        corrected_w[num_y[n]][num_x[n]] = np.sum(ar)/np.count_nonzero(ar)
        corrected_org_I[num_y[n]][num_x[n]] = np.sum(ar2)/np.count_nonzero(ar2)

    c = np.mean(corrected_w) # constant

    ## flat field correction
    FFC = np.uint16(np.divide(c*(corrected_org_I-B), (corrected_w-B)))

    F = np.fft.fft2(FFC)
    Fshift = np.fft.fftshift(F)
    magnitude_spectrum3 = 20*np.log(np.abs(Fshift))

    [row, col] = org_I.shape
    [row2, col2] = np.array([row, col], dtype=np.int) // 2
    row2_range = 1
    col2_range = 2
    Fshift[:row2-row2_range-1, col2-col2_range-1:col2+col2_range] = 0
    Fshift[row2+row2_range:, col2-col2_range-1:col2+col2_range] = 0
    fishift = np.fft.ifftshift(Fshift)
    result = np.fft.ifft2(fishift)

    print("time :", time.time() - start)

    cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\jhjoo\Desktop\corrected_org_I (' + str(i) + ').png', result)
    cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\jhjoo\Desktop\corrected_org_I (' + str(i) + ').png', corrected_org_I)
    cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\jhjoo\Desktop\corrected_w (' + str(i) + ').png', corrected_w)
```

Comment: what do you mean by *i is stuck in for loop.*?  where is your `for` loop? Also provide error message

Comment: Mention the error name

Comment: ```<built-in function imwrite> returned NULL without setting an error```

Comment: ```i``` is stuck in ```for loop```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv2.imwrite` takes first argument as a `string`, not a `list`. You should fix your code as following:

```
cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\Desktop\result (' + str(i) + ').png', result) #result is 16bit image
```

Comment: I tried, but ```Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'``` occured ㅜㅜ